# Indexing a tibble makes data type undetectable

Tags: r

I have the following tibble:

```
test <- tibble(
  id = c("John","Jacob","Jingleheimer","Schmidt"),
  score = c(2,4,6,8)
)
```

The variable "score" is numeric. When I run the command `is.numeric`, I get the following:

```
> is.numeric(test$score)
[1] TRUE
```

But when I try to do the same thing, only this time referencing the column by its index, I get a different output:

```
> is.numeric(test[,2])
[1] FALSE
```

I'm confused as to why I'm getting such disparate output to two versions of the same command. Why can't `is.numeric` detect the data type when I use indexing?

Comment: `base::data.frame[,2]` will return a vector. Every other frame-variant (`tbl_df` and `data.table`) returns a single-column frame. Use `is.numeric(test[[2]])` if you want to do that by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing works differently for tibbles and data.frames.  See [this](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/wip/subset.html).

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(
  id = c("John","Jacob","Jingleheimer","Schmidt"),
  score = c(2,4,6,8)
)
 
class(test[, 2])
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(as.data.frame(test)[, 2])
## [1] "numeric"
```

The basic difference is that data frames default to drop = TRUE whereas tibbles default to drop = FALSE.

```
class(test[, 2])
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(test[, 2, drop = FALSE]) # same
## [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(test[, 2, drop = TRUE])
## [1] "numeric"


class(as.data.frame(test)[, 2])
## [1] "numeric"

class(as.data.frame(test)[, 2, drop = TRUE]) # same
## [1] "numeric"

class(as.data.frame(test)[, 2, drop = FALSE])
## [1] "data.frame"
```

Also note

```
class(pull(test, 2))
## [1] "numeric"

class(test[[2]])
## [1] "numeric"

class(unlist(test[, 2]))
## [1] "numeric"

sapply(test, class)
##          id       score 
## "character"   "numeric"
```